# Can I execute the "cd" command to change directories using PHP CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, cd

I created a script using PHP CLI that I would like to have `cd` me into a directory based upon my command line input.

While I can get the PHP execution commands to echo output (e.g. echo `ls -al`), I cannot get them to run `cd`.

I have searched a lot online to find the solution, but have come up empty.

Comment: Afaik `cd` is a builtin. You could prefix it with bash: `/bin/bash -c 'cd <path>; ls'`. That could work, not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `cd` as it would run in a subshell, and the changed working directory would be lost when you returned to PHP before issuing the next command.

Use [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, everyone. I'll just create a bash script instead.

Comment: For anyone with a similar goal, my solution was to abandon PHP CLI for this. The `chdir` function changes the directory pointer within the PHP script (not my desired result here). Bash scripts using "sh" command also did not work. I had to use "source" command instead (note PHP CLI apparently does not allow execution of source command). My end result is basically `source goto-dir.sh dirname`, which executes bash code `cd /path/$1/web` (web is the docroot, $1 is the project name -- I hope to have a lot of projects, and need a quick way to get to any chosen docroot).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `chdir` from php, running `cd` from `exec, system, shell_exec` etc. only change directories in subprocesses called by php, every new system call will start in php current working directory.